mpu6050 readings on Arduino UNO for calculating roll,pitch and yaw. Issue with accel readings
I'm using the mpu6050 to read the data from accel and gyros and use them together with a complementary filter to get roll, pitch and yaw. My problem is that the accel readings are wrong and I don't understand if the sensor is not working properly or something in my code is wrong.
In standstill I have reasonable value but when I tilt my robot the gyros still gives me reasonable values whereas the accel value are always in the range [-1;1].

Robot standstill:
aX: 0.06 - aY: 0.00 - aZ: 1.06                                                            - gX: -0.11   - gY: 0.00  - gZ: -0.03 - Roll: -0.04   - Pitch: -0.00  - Yaw: -0.01
Tilt to the right:
aX: 0.39    -  aY: 0.92 - aZ: 1.12 -
gX: 4.36    - gY: 0.73 -     gZ: -1.35 -
Roll: 8.29  - Pitch: 1.39   - Yaw: -2.62

As you can see the Accel readings remain in a range that's not correct.
I hope to get some clarification.
Below the code:
#include <arduino.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>
#include <wire.h>
static double previousTime = 0;

struct accel_data{
  int16_t tmp_x = 0;
  int16_t tmp_y = 0;
  int16_t tmp_z = 0;
  int16_t ax = 0;
  int16_t ay = 0;
  int16_t az = 0;
};

struct gyros_data {
  int16_t gx = 0;
  int16_t gy = 0;
  int16_t gz = 0;
  int16_t tmp_x = 0;
  int16_t tmp_y = 0;
  int16_t tmp_z = 0;
};

struct accel_gyros{
  float gx = 0;
  float gy = 0;
  float gz = 0;
  float ax = 0;
  float ay = 0;
  float az = 0;
  float roll = 0;
  float pitch = 0;
  float yaw = 0;
};
class MPU6050_obj{
  public:
    accel_data a_data;
    gyros_data g_data;
    accel_gyros data;

    void calibration(const motor_setup&, accel_data& , gyros_data&, MPU6050&);
    void data_processing(const accel_data& ,const gyros_data&, accel_gyros&);
};
MPU6050_obj myMPU;
MPU6050 mpu_lib;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  mpu_lib.initialize();
  myMPU.calibration(App_motor, myMPU.a_data, myMPU.g_data, mpu_lib);
}
void loop() {

  
  if(irrecv.decode(&results)){
    if(static_cast<button>(results.value) == button::unknown){
      Serial.println("Ignoring erroneous signal");
      irrecv.resume();
      return; 
    }
    switch (button_prs) {

      case button::three: //mpu
          myMPU.data_processing(myMPU.a_data, myMPU.g_data, myMPU.data);
      break;
       case button::five:
       //something
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }
      irrecv.resume();
  }

}
void MPU6050_obj::calibration(const motor_setup& App_motor, accel_data& a_data, gyros_data& g_data, MPU6050& mpu_lib){ //There are better ways to implement this fcn 

  int16_t accel_x, accel_y, accel_z, gyros_x, gyros_y, gyros_z;
  int n = 250, i = 0;
  // Set gyroscope sensitivity to ±250 dps (131) 
  mpu_lib.setFullScaleGyroRange(MPU6050_GYRO_FS_250); //I'm using ±250dps and ±2G because of my robot behaviour (small turns, flat ground mostly, no rapid accelerations)
  // Set accelerometer sensitivity to ±2 G (16384)
  mpu_lib.setFullScaleAccelRange(MPU6050_ACCEL_FS_4); 

  //reading_test();
  if(mpu_lib.testConnection() && App_motor.get_pin() == LOW){  //add this piece of code beacuse cal has to happen in standstill condition 
    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
      mpu_lib.getAcceleration(&accel_x, &accel_y, &accel_z);
      mpu_lib.getRotation(&gyros_x, &gyros_y, &gyros_z);
      a_data.tmp_x += accel_x;
      a_data.tmp_y += accel_y;
      a_data.tmp_z += accel_z;
      g_data.tmp_x += gyros_x;
      g_data.tmp_y += gyros_y;
      g_data.tmp_z += gyros_z;
      delay(10);
    }
    a_data.ax = a_data.tmp_x/n;
    a_data.ay = a_data.tmp_y/n;
    a_data.az = a_data.tmp_z/n;
    g_data.gx = g_data.tmp_x/n;
    g_data.gy = g_data.tmp_y/n;
    g_data.gz = g_data.tmp_z/n;
  }
  else Serial.print("MPU non identified");
}

void MPU6050_obj::data_processing(const accel_data& a_data ,const gyros_data& g_data, accel_gyros& data){

  int s_a = 16384, s_g = 131; //accelerometer/gyroscope sensitivity
  float alpha = 0.98;//weight factor
  float a_roll = 0, a_pitch = 0, g_roll = 0, g_pitch = 0, yaw = 0;
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();  
  float dt = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000000.0;  // Calculate dt in seconds
  int16_t accel_x, accel_y, accel_z, gyros_x, gyros_y, gyros_z;
  previousTime = currentTime; //PreviousTime is defined as static

  //Start measurements
  mpu_lib.getAcceleration(&accel_x, &accel_y, &accel_z);
  mpu_lib.getRotation(&gyros_x, &gyros_y, &gyros_z);

  //Subtracting the bias (calculated in calibration function) and dividing by sensitivy in order to convert raw values to dps and gravitation force (G)
  data.ax = (static_cast<float>(accel_x) -  static_cast<float>(a_data.ax))/s_a;
  data.ay = (static_cast<float>(accel_y) -  static_cast<float>(a_data.ay))/s_a;
  data.az = (static_cast<float>(accel_z) -  static_cast<float>(a_data.az))/s_a;
  data.gx = ((static_cast<float>(gyros_x) -  static_cast<float>(g_data.gx))/s_g) * (PI / 180.0);  //rad/s
  data.gy = ((static_cast<float>(gyros_y) -  static_cast<float>(g_data.gy))/s_g) * (PI / 180.0);  //rad/s
  data.gz = ((static_cast<float>(gyros_z) -  static_cast<float>(g_data.gz))/s_g) * (PI / 180.0);

  //Calculating roll and pitch from accel readings
  a_roll = atan2(data.ay, sqrt(pow(data.ax, 2) + pow(data.az, 2)));
  a_pitch = atan2(-data.ax, sqrt(pow(data.ay, 2) + pow(data.az, 2))); 

  //Integrate gyroscope data for angular velocity
  yaw += data.gz * dt; 
  g_roll += data.gx * dt;
  g_pitch += data.gy * dt;

  // Complementary filter
  data.roll = alpha * g_roll + (1 - alpha) * a_roll;
  data.pitch = alpha * g_pitch + (1 - alpha) * a_pitch;
  data.yaw = yaw;

}

